# An error occurred while listing S3 relations: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created lambda function with s3 bucket required access and i am trying to create s3 events trigger but i am getting access denied error.

**lambda.tf**

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "s3-lambdas" {
  filename         = "./s3-lambdas.zip"
  function_name    = "s3-lambdas"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(s3-lambdas)
  role             = module.lambda_role.arn
  handler          = "s3-lambdas.lambda_handler"
  runtime          = "python3.9"
  timeout          = 200
  description      = "invoke glue job"
  depends_on       = [module.lambda_role]
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "s3_lambdas_s3_events" {
  depends_on    = [aws_lambda_function.s3-lambdas]
  statement_id  = "AllowS3Invoke"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = aws_lambda_function.s3-lambdas.function_name
  principal     = "s3.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn    = "arn:aws:s3:::${module.bucket-name.name}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notifications" {
  bucket = module.bucket-name.name
  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = aws_lambda_function.s3-lambdas.arn
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_prefix       = "abc/def/"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_lambda_permission.s3_lambdas_s3_events]
}
```

and my lambda role which contains s3 full access.
**s3.tf**

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-s3-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-s3-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

even though i am getting `An error occurred while listing S3 relations: Access Denied` when i tried to create s3 triggers.

**Edited**

```
output "bucket_name" {
  value = module.bucket-name.name
}

bucket_name = dev-s3-bucket

output "iam_dev_arn" {
  value = module.lambda_role.arn
}

iam_dev_arn = arn:aws:iam::0123456789:role/s3-lambda-role

output "div_arn" {
  value = aws_lambda_function.s3-lambdas.arn
}

div_arn = arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:0123456789:function:s3-lambdas
```

**assume_role_policy**

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

i have added the outputs related to module

**s3-lambdas**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import boto3
import urllib
import os

print ('Loading function')

glue = boto3.client('glue')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    gluejobname = os.environ['glue_job']

    try: 
        runId = glue.start_job_run(JobName=gluejobname)
        status = glue.get_job_run(JobName=gluejobname, RunId=runId['JobRunId'])
        print("Job Status : ", status['JobRun']['JobRunState'], "runId",runId)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": os.environ['glue_job'] + " Job started"
    }
```

s3 bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "denyInsecureTransport",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-s3-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-s3-bucket"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add `module.bucket-name.name` to the question? In other words, can you add the module call plus the outputs you have defined on the module level? Also, are the S3 permissions everything you have assigned to the Lambda role? Are there any trust policies, i.e., do you have `assume_role_policy` defined for the Lambda?

Comment: @Marko E edited the question with outputs

Comment: Are there any ACLs and/or bucket policies on the bucket? Is the bucket owned by the same account where the Lambda is in? Are the objects owned by the account where the bucket is in?

Comment: bucket and lambdas are owned by same account and don't have any bucket policies

Comment: Your code is invalid TF code, and its impossibile to get the error you are reporting. For example, `filebase64sha256(s3-lambdas)` is simply not a valid TF code. If you get the error you are reporting, it means that your real code is different then in the question, which means it will be nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: @Marcin i have added s3-lambdas code in the question. code is valid

Comment: @HariBabu And your IAM policy for Lambda has correct permissions for using Glue as well?

Comment: i have attached glue policy to lambda role as well

Comment: @Marko E there is a bucket policy attached. i added that in the question

Answer (score 0):

In your S3 bucket policy can you make the following change and retry:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::dev-s3-bucket/abc/def/*"   <-- change this
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i tadded this and tried but same error i am getting

Comment: oh okay.. are you sure about the bucket_name, lambda arn etc? cos rest of the details looks to be fine.. and are you sure that your lambda has this correct role attached?

Comment: yes i checked. everything is good